# ¿Cómo deshabilitar la verificación de foreign key (llave foránea) temporalmente?

Tags: mysql

En MySQL, tengo la necesidad de truncar un par de tablas que están relacionadas, digamos Maestro y Detalle. Si hago `TRUNCATE Detalle` funciona sin problemas, pero si hago `TRUNCATE Maestro` me salta el siguiente error:

> ERROR 1701 (42000): Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`mybasedatos`.`detalle`, CONSTRAINT `detalle_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idMaestro`) REFERENCES `mybasedatos`.`maestro` (`id`))

No quiero remover los foreign keys porque las tablas tienen miles de registros y puede tomar mucho tiempo. ¿Existe alguna manera de deshabilitar esta verificación de llaves foráneas temporalmente para limpiar la data y luego rehabilitarlo?

Adaptado de:

- [How to temporarily disable a foreign key constraint in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15501673/1065197)
- [truncate foreign key constrained table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5452760/1065197)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sí, es posible. Solo se necesita cambiar el valor de la variable global [`FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks). Para ello, se necesitan permisos de administrador en MySQL (como root).

El resultado sería:

```sql
-- Deshabilitar verificación de llaves foráneas
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
-- Truncar las tablas necesarias
TRUNCATE Detalle;
TRUNCATE Maestro;
-- Rehabilitar verificación de llaves foráneas
-- Este paso es importante, no olvidarlo
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```